# subfigures break figure numbering with sidecaptions from sidenotes package

Tags: captions, subcaption, sidenotes

I am setting my captions into the margin with the `sidenotes` package. I also use the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaptions` quite a lot to annotate subplots and refer to them.

I now noticed that this combination breaks the numbering. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, left=33mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=\baselineskip, 
          marginparwidth=43mm, marginparsep=1em}

% ********************************************************************
% captions, taking use of the margins
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{stdstyle}{
    format=hang,                 % caption hangs behind label
    justification=justified,     % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,       % always left-align caption
    labelsep=quad,               % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize            % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outerragged}{\ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidestyle}{
    format=plain, %indention=2em, % whole line for caption, with indent after first
    justification=outerragged,    % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,        % always left-align caption
    labelsep=newline,             % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                 % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize             % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{
    style = sidestyle,
    labelsep=quad
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widetable}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{
    style = sidestyle,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=newline
}
\usepackage[style = stdstyle]{caption}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    justification=raggedright,
    labelfont=sc
]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{for the numbers}
\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 1
    \label{fig:1}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:1}

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 2. this one has two images but nor subfigures
    \label{fig:2}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:2}

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 3. this one has two images and uses subfigures with captions to address the subplots
    \label{fig:3}
    }
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{some text for 3a}
        \label{fig:3:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{some text for 3b}
        \label{fig:3:b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:3} and then there is something important about \autoref{fig:3:a} and \autoref{fig:3:b} but why does this latter one increase the figure counter?

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 4
    \label{fig:4}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:4} but hey it's Figure 1.5 now...

\end{document}
```

I get properly numbered figures 1.1 and 1.2 which do both not use the `subfigure` environment. Figure 1.3 is correctly numbered but referring to the subfigures increases the counter to 1.4a and 1.4b instead of 1.3a.
Furthermore, the next figure is numbered 1.5 skipping 1.4 entirely.

Apparently the sufigure seems to open a new figure or at least to increase the figure counter. The observed behavior is independent of referencing the subfigures or not. The next figure is always numbered incorrectly.

Does someone have an idea what is actually happening? And, most importantly, how to fix it?

To directly adress some potential questions and to give you an idea what alternative approaches should provide in functionality, here some reasons why I do it this way:
I am putting the caption into the margin as there is (i) space and (ii) I also set the legend for the entire set of subplots there, this is much more convenient than putting it in one of the plots and I have more freedom in formatting than in a caption below the figure.
I am using the `subcaption` package because it works best and the syntax is easier and shorter than for the KOMA-sidecaption. Especially the caption may be longer than the figure itself is high and the caption text then runs next to the main text. The KOMA approach does not allow this (or I did not get it to work).

If someone has a different approach allowing the above features that would also be very welcome to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\sidecaption{...}` increment caption number, consequently captions in `subfigure` "see" incremented value of the counter `caption` and not the value, which use `\sidecaption`. This means, that the `\sidecaption{...}` had to be after `subfigure` environments. With this change your MWE gives expected result:

[image]

**Edit:**
In this change you need consider, that `\sidecaption{...}` is defined in package `sidenotes` and unfortunately hasn't option for choose its position regarding to float content. It only enable manually shifting of caption position. This can be exploited as shown in above figure by `\sidecaption[][-6em]{...}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, left=33mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=\baselineskip,
          marginparwidth=43mm, marginparsep=1em}
% ********************************************************************
% captions, taking use of the margins
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{stdstyle}{
    format=hang,                 % caption hangs behind label
    justification=justified,     % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,       % always left-align caption
    labelsep=quad,               % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize            % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outerragged}{\ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidestyle}{
    format=plain, %indention=2em, % whole line for caption, with indent after first
    justification=outerragged,    % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,        % always left-align caption
    labelsep=newline,             % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                 % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize             % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{
    style = sidestyle,
    labelsep=quad
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widetable}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{
    style = sidestyle,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=newline
}
\usepackage[style = stdstyle]{caption}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    justification=raggedright,
    labelfont=sc
]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{for the numbers}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 1
    \label{fig:1}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:1}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 2. this one has two images but nor subfigures
    \label{fig:2}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:2}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{some text for 3a}
        \label{fig:3:a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{some text for 3b}
        \label{fig:3:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \sidecaption[][-6em]% <-- addedoptions for manual adjustment of caption position
                        {caption of figure 3. this one has two images and uses subfigures with captions to address the subplots
    \label{fig:3}
    }
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:3} and then there is something important about \autoref{fig:3:a} and \autoref{fig:3:b} but why does this latter one increase the figure counter?

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 4
    \label{fig:4}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:4} but hey it's Figure 1.5 now...
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a good point and solves the problem. However, then, the caption is aligned with the bottom of the figure not its top. Is there a quick solution for that, too?

Comment: @Martin, I'm not familiar with `scrbook`, so in this I can't help you.

Comment: I also noticed that the sidecaption text starts below the float if the images take up all the space in the line (as in my case). That is good to know...

Comment: @Martin, since `\sidecaption` is defined by `sidenotes` package, you can exploit its possibilities for manual adjustment of caption position. See edit of my answer.

Comment: That is true, but than I would have to know the height of my figure to not adjust every caption's positions manually... I will post an new quenstion on this.

Comment: @Martin, one way to solve your problem is use some other package for side caption. Short look in `scrbook` documentation show me, that this document class provide similar (but as I observed more complicated) facility.

Comment: I know and I tried that too but the results are not as good (see above) ;)

Answer (score 3):

As explained by Zarko, the `subfigure` environment increases the `figure` counter. A suggestion for an ugly hack would be to decrease the counter manually every time you call subfigures by adding a `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` to your code. This has to be done *within* the `figure` environment just before you call the first `subfigure` to work for both figure numbering and referencing.

That way, your `sidecaption` will still be top-aligned with the figure without shifting it up manually for every single figure. I'm not sure though if messing with the counters will create any other nasty problems...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, left=33mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=\baselineskip, 
          marginparwidth=43mm, marginparsep=1em}

% ********************************************************************
% captions, taking use of the margins
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{stdstyle}{
    format=hang,                 % caption hangs behind label
    justification=justified,     % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,       % always left-align caption
    labelsep=quad,               % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize            % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outerragged}{\ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidestyle}{
    format=plain, %indention=2em, % whole line for caption, with indent after first
    justification=outerragged,    % caption is a normal paragraph
    singlelinecheck=false,        % always left-align caption
    labelsep=newline,             % quad separator behind label
    labelfont=sc,                 % label in scshape
    font=footnotesize             % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{
    style = sidestyle,
    labelsep=quad
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widetable}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{style = stdstyle}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{
    style = sidestyle,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=newline
}
\usepackage[style = stdstyle]{caption}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    justification=raggedright,
    labelfont=sc
]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{for the numbers}
\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 1
    \label{fig:1}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:1}

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 2. this one has two images but nor subfigures
    \label{fig:2}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:2}

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 3. this one has two images and uses subfigures with captions to address the subplots
    \label{fig:3}
    }
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{some text for 3a}
        \label{fig:3:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{some text for 3b}
        \label{fig:3:b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:3} and then there is something important about \autoref{fig:3:a} and \autoref{fig:3:b} but why does this latter one increase the figure counter?

\begin{figure}
    \sidecaption{caption of figure 4
    \label{fig:4}
    }
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
some text and we talk about \autoref{fig:4} but hey it's Figure 1.5 now...

\end{document}
```