# How to get the height of current float?

Tags: floats, captions, sidenotes

I am using the `sidecpation` from the `sidenotes` package to typeset my captions into the margin. I would like these captions to be aligned with the top of the floats.

One can simply put the `sidecaption` command first within the float. However, in combination with subfigures, this breaks the numbering ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358010/subfigures-break-figure-numbering-with-sidecaptions-from-sidenotes-package)). As a result of this problem, I am putting the `sidecaption` command as last and reposition it using the optional `offset` argument. Doing so manually and achieving a consistent layout for a lot of figures is quite hard and I would like to automate that.

Giving the height of the current figure as offset, would solve this problem in a simple and straightforward manner. But how do I get this length?

Please note that I am not interested in the height of a single image but in the height of the entire float which may consist of several images in `subfigure` environments with individual subcaptions. 
It would be a bonus if the approach would also cover `tabulars`.

Other options to top-align the sidecaption are also appreciated. They should however fulfill the requirements stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358010/subfigures-break-figure-numbering-with-sidecaptions-from-sidenotes-package).

A short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, left=33mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=\baselineskip, 
          marginparwidth=43mm, marginparsep=1em}

% ********************************************************************
% captions, taking use of the margins
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{stdstyle}{
    format=hang,                 % caption hangs behind label
    justification=justified,    
    labelsep=quad,               % quad separator behind label
    font=footnotesize            % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outerragged}{\ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidestyle}{
    format=plain, %indention=2em, % whole line for caption, with indent after first
    justification=outerragged,    % caption is a normal paragraph
    labelsep=newline,             % quad separator behind label
    font=footnotesize             % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{
    style = sidestyle,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=newline
}
\usepackage[style = stdstyle]{caption}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    justification=raggedright
]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{for the numbers}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption{some text for a}
        \label{fig:3:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{some text for b}
        \label{fig:3:b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \sidecaption[LoF][-2em]{I want to be aligned at the top of the float
    \label{fig:3}
    }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the `\sidecaption` to the entire float, simply put the contents (excepting the `\sidecaption`) into a minipage, then use `\raisebox` to move the baseline,

The value 7.69997pt was obtained by measuring the height of a `\strut` inside the caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=10mm, left=33mm, right=46mm, bottom=46mm, headsep=\baselineskip, 
          marginparwidth=43mm, marginparsep=1em}

% ********************************************************************
% captions, taking use of the margins
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{stdstyle}{
    format=hang,                 % caption hangs behind label
    justification=justified,    
    labelsep=quad,               % quad separator behind label
    font=footnotesize            % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{outerragged}{\ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidestyle}{
    format=plain, %indention=2em, % whole line for caption, with indent after first
    justification=outerragged,    % caption is a normal paragraph
    labelsep=newline,             % quad separator behind label
    font=footnotesize             % all in small font size
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{
    style = sidestyle,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=newline
}
\usepackage[style = stdstyle]{caption}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    justification=raggedright
]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{for the numbers}

\begin{figure}
\raisebox{\dimexpr 7.69997pt-\height}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{some text for a}
        \label{fig:3:a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{some text for b}
        \label{fig:3:b}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \end{minipage}}\nobreak
    \sidecaption[LoF][-2em]{I want to be aligned at the top of the float
    \label{fig:3}
    }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I do not quite understand what it does but it works like a charm :)

Comment: Horizontal alignment is done along the baseline.  For text, the baseline is the bottom of letters (except for descenders like g and y).  One can use \raisebox{-\height} to move the baseline to the top, no matter where it was originally.  Note that while \sidecaption takes up no space, it can still force a line break (hence the \nobreak).